# Pytest PropertyMock not returning different attribute values

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to mock an attribute of an object to return different values when invoked. Right now I have

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
      self.a1 = [1, 1]
      self.a2 = [2, 2]
      self.a3 = [3, 3]
   def run(self):
      for i in self.a2:
         print(f"val in a2: {i}")

def test_A(mocker):
   myObj = A()
   myObj.a2 = mocker.PropertyMock(side_effect = [[2, 3], [3,4], [4,5]])
   myObj.run()
```

is giving `TypeError: 'PropertyMock' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the way to do this is to grab the type of the object and mock the property of the type. The solution is therefore

```
def test_A(mocker):
    myObj = A()
    type(myObj).a2 = mocker.PropertyMock(
        side_effect=iter([[2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]])
    )
    myObj.run()
```